# Use SMB2 protocol while mounting CIFS Share on a Unix client

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, smb2

I am trying to mount a CIFS share on my Unix client. My Unix client has Samba installed.

```
# smbstatus 
Samba version 3.6.9-151.el6

sudo mount -t cifs -o domain=domain_name,user=user_name,password=password,vers=2.1 //*ip_address*/share mount_directory
```

I looked into the packet traces in Wireshark and SMB1 protocol is used during Negotiation of requests.

From the Samba wiki page, I see that Samba 3.6 supports SMB2. How can I use SMB2 protocol instead ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your linux kernel since you're mounting using the kernel mount.cifs module.

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS